# como actualizar la información de otra pagina con php?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

tengo una pagina en php donde guardo por ejemplo un producto , me guarda correctamente el producto. despues de guardar me envia a otra pagina donde se ve todos los productos, lo malo es que cuando me envia a la otra pagina no aparece el ultimo que agrege , tengo que actualizar la pagina para que recien aparesca este ultimo agregado les paso mi codigo

> GUARDO crear_promociones.php

```
  <?php

    include_once '../logica/conexion.php';
    include_once '../logica/promocionBean.php';
    include_once '../logica/promocionDao.php';
    ?><!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title> MacherMotors |  Carwash</title>
        <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
        <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.5 -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <!-- Font Awesome -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <!-- Ionicons -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
        <!-- Theme style -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/loading.css">
        <!-- AdminLTE Skins. Choose a skin from the css/skins
             folder instead of downloading all of them to reduce the load. -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/timepicker/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css">
        <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

    </head>
    <body class="hold-transition skin-black sidebar-mini">
    <div class="wrapper">

        <?php include_once "./componentes/menu.php";?>

        <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
            <section class="content-header">
                <h1>
                    Crear Promociones
                </h1>
            </section>

            <!-- Main content -->
            <section class="content">
                <!-- /.row -->

                <form  action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">


                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <div class="box">
                            <div class="box-header">
                                <h3 class="box-title"></h3>

                                <div class="box box-danger">
                                    <div class="box-header with-border">
                                        <h3 class="box-title">Promocion</h3>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="box-body">
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Nombre</label>
                                                <input type="text" name="nombre_pro" id="nobre_pro" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre promocion ...">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Fecha incio</label>
                                                <input type="date" name="fecha_incio" id="fecha_incio" class="form-control" placeholder="fecha de inicio ...">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Fecha Fin</label>
                                                <input type="date" name="fecha_fin" id="fecha_fin" class="form-control" placeholder="fecha de fin ...">
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Imagen</label>
                                                <input type="file" name="image_url" id="image_url" class="form-control">
                                            </div>

                                            <button name="btn-guardar" id="btn-guardar" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>

                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div id="file-preview-zone">
                                            </div>

                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                    <!-- /.box-body -->
                                </div>
                            </div><!-- /.box-header -->
                            <div class="spinner" style="display:none;">
                                <div></div>
                                <div></div>
                                <div></div>
                                <div></div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="cargarTablaAtencion"  name="cargarTablaAtencion" class="box-body table-responsive no-padding">


                            </div><!-- /.box-body -->
                        </div><!-- /.box -->
                    </div>
                </div>

                </form>
                <div id="resultado">
                    <?php
                    if (isset($_POST['btn-guardar'])) {
                        $negocio = new PromocionDAO();
                        $bean = new PromocionBean();
                        $bean->setNombrePromocion(utf8_decode($_POST['nombre_pro']));
                        $bean->setFechaInicio(($_POST['fecha_incio']));
                        $bean->setFechaFin(($_POST['fecha_fin']));
                        $bean->setEstado(1);
                        $bean->setFechaCreacion(date('Y-m-d'));

                        //  $bean->setImageUrl(($_POST['fecha_fin']));

                        $target_path = "uploads/";
                        if ($_FILES['image_url']["error"] > 0) {
                            echo "Error: " . $_FILES['image_url']['error'] . "<br>";
                        } else {
                            $bean->setImageUrl($_FILES['image_url']['name']);
                              move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image_url']['tmp_name'],  $target_path . $_FILES['image_url']['name']);
                        }


                        try {

                            $negocio->agregar($bean);
    ?>

                            <script>
                                alert("La promcion se guardo correctamente! ");


 location.href = "ver_promociones.php";
                        </script>
               <?php

                    } catch (FailedExceptionQuery $ex) {

                    } catch (FailedExceptionBD $exc) {

                    }

                }
              ?>
            </div>
        </section><!-- /.content -->
    </div><!-- /.content-wrapper -->
    <?php include_once "./componentes/footer.php";?>

    <!-- Add the sidebar's background. This div must be placed
         immediately after the control sidebar -->
    <div class="control-sidebar-bg"></div>
</div><!-- ./wrapper -->

<!-- jQuery 2.1.4 -->
<script src="plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<?php include_once "./js/enviojs.php";?>
<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.5 -->
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Slimscroll -->
<script src="plugins/timepicker/bootstrap-timepicker.min.js"></script>

<script src="plugins/slimScroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<!-- FastClick -->
<script src="plugins/fastclick/fastclick.min.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE App -->
<script src="dist/js/app.min.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE for demo purposes -->
<script src="dist/js/demo.js"></script>

<script>

    document.getElementById("image_url").onchange = function(e) {
        // Creamos el objeto de la clase FileReader
        var reader = new FileReader();

        // Leemos el archivo subido y se lo pasamos a nuestro fileReader
        reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);

        // Le decimos que cuando este listo ejecute el código interno
        reader.onload = function(){
            var preview = document.getElementById('file-preview-zone'),
                image = document.createElement('img');

            image.src = reader.result;

            preview.innerHTML = '';
            preview.append(image);
        };
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

LISTA (ver_promociones.php)

```
<?php

include_once '../logica/conexion.php';
include_once '../logica/promocionBean.php';
include_once '../logica/promocionDao.php';
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title> MacherMotors |  Carwash</title>
    <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.5 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Ionicons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
    <!-- Theme style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/loading.css">
    <!-- AdminLTE Skins. Choose a skin from the css/skins
         folder instead of downloading all of them to reduce the load. -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/timepicker/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css">
    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>
<body class="hold-transition skin-black sidebar-mini">
<div class="wrapper">

    <?php include_once "./componentes/menu.php";?>

    <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <section class="content">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="box">
                        <div class="box-header">
                            <h3 class="box-title">Lista de promociones</h3>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.box-header -->
                        <div class="box-body">
                            <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                                <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Nombre</th>
                                    <th>Fecha inicio</th>
                                    <th>Fecha fin</th>
                                    <th>Estado</th>
                                    <th>Acciones</th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                <?php
                                $negocio = new PromocionDAO();
                                try {
                                    $resultado = $negocio->listar();
                                    while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()):
                                        ?>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><?php echo $fila['nombre_promocion']; ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $fila['fecha_inicio']; ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $fila['fecha_Fin']; ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $fila['estado']; ?></td>
                                            <td>
                                                <button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <?php
                                    endwhile;

                                } catch (FailedExceptionQuery $ex) {
                                    echo "<script>$.pnotify({delay:500,title:\"ERROR\",text:\"Hubo un problema al generar la consulta\",type:\"error\"});</script>";
                                } catch (FailedExceptionNoIdentificado $ex2) {
                                    echo "<script>$.pnotify({delay:500,title:\"INFORMACION\",text:\"No hay todavia ningun contacto agregado\",type:\"info\"});</script>";
                                } catch (FailedExceptionBD $exc) {
                                    echo "<script>$.pnotify({delay:500,title:\"ERROR\",text:\"Hubo u2n error al conectar la base de datos\",type:\"error\"});</script>";
                                }
                                ?>
                                </tbody>
                                <tfoot>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Nombre</th>
                                    <th>Fecha inicio</th>
                                    <th>Fecha fin</th>
                                    <th>Estado</th>
                                </tr>
                                </tfoot>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.box-body -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.box -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.col -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
        </section>
    </div><!-- /.content-wrapper -->
    <?php include_once "./componentes/footer.php";?>

    <!-- Add the sidebar's background. This div must be placed
         immediately after the control sidebar -->
    <div class="control-sidebar-bg"></div>
</div><!-- ./wrapper -->

<!-- jQuery 2.1.4 -->
<script src="plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<?php include_once "./js/enviojs.php";?>
<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.5 -->
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- data table -->
<script src="plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>

<!-- Slimscroll -->
<script src="plugins/timepicker/bootstrap-timepicker.min.js"></script>

<script src="plugins/slimScroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<!-- FastClick -->
<script src="plugins/fastclick/fastclick.min.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE App -->
<script src="dist/js/app.min.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE for demo purposes -->
<script src="dist/js/demo.js"></script>

<script>

    $(function () {
        $('#example1').DataTable()
        $('#example2').DataTable({
            'paging'      : true,
            'lengthChange': false,
            'searching'   : false,
            'ordering'    : true,
            'info'        : true,
            'autoWidth'   : false
        })
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```